# Observe full sql log from core data (without placeholders)

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

Is it possible to somehow see the full sql log from core data operations, with the actual values being inserted, etc. This:

`-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` shows only placeholders, like this:

> CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZFOO(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZACTIVE,
>   ZISENROLLED, ZNAME, ZPACKAGETYPE, ZPRODUCTID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?)

Maybe I can do this at database level - force somehow sql to keep a log?

Comment: Try setting `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3` - I think it might include the values.

Comment: @pbasdf ohhh, that's a log level! I thought it was just a boolean flag. It works, thanks! (you can write it as an answer, to select it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify different values for the SQLDebug flag, to get more detail.  I think SQLDebug 3 will provide the values:

```
 -com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3
```